# Unable to convert IIS web.config URL Friendly to .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm migrating a web application from a Windows (IIS) server to a Linux (Apache) and I have been a few days trying to *adapt* the application, configs, etc. for Linux/Apache.

Everyting is working except the url friendly I was using with Windows/IIS. And I don't know if this is actually a URL Friendly, a simple redirect or anything else.

This is what I want:

I have a 'app.php' file which is like the main application 'index', and shows different 'pages' depending on the old/ugly url parameters:

```
 https://example.com/app.php?qpage=5&qsubpage=2&action=new
```

Instead of writting this, I want to use friendly urls like this:

```
 https://example.com/section5/?qsubpage=2&action=new
```

(Please notice that the second and third parameters 'qsubpage' and 'action' are optional!)

Ok, with IIS and this lines in web.config, it works fine:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="app.php?qpage={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Then, in 'app.php' file I get the current URI and (optional) parameters to show one content or another.

However, I can't reach to get it working with .htaccess.

This is what I have know. It works fine **only if there is just one parameter:**

If I go to...

```
 https://example.com/section5
```

...it shows the correct 'page' correctly.

However, if I go to...

```
 https://example.com/section5/?qsubpage=2
 or
 https://example.com/section5?qsubpage=2
```

...'qsubpage' is ignored.

If I go to

```
 https://example.com/section5&qsubpage=2
```

...I get a '404: url not found' error (however it works in Windows)

This is my .htaccess rule:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([A-Z-a-z-0-9]+)/?$ simplygest.php?qpage=$1&qsubpage=$2 [L]
```

I have tried some online mod_rewrite generators and even web.config to .htaccess converters online with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please do let us know `&qsubpage=2&action=new` is a constant string in urls? and you need to only add value from `section` coming from url, kindly confirm once.

Comment: 'qsubpage', 'action' and other params are optional. 'section' is variable. For example, these are valid working urls: example.com/products, example.com/history?qsubpage=2, example.com/config...

Comment: Could you please do let us know exact url which user will be hitting and where it should be redirected in backend?

Comment: Users and internal links go to example.com/history, example.com/config, example.com/products, example.com/customers, etc. None of those paths actually exist. There isn't any /history, /customers, etc. subdirs. Some of those urls can have optional parameters like ?qsubpage=2&action=new. I need to preserve those params in the url as I then use PHP $_GET to get them. All of these urls go to the SAME .php page (app.php for example). In that page, I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get the /subdir part and $_GET for the possible optional parameters and show each content.